# PHP SQL --- Edit part of form not working

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to trouble shoot the below to make the update sql work but it seems the $edit_id variable is outputting null. I have a form similar to this which is working fine, although the below is more complex but I cannot find what is missing to make it work.

Any suggestions on where the fault is guys?

```
    <?php 
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ares/aresStore/core/init.php';
    include 'includes/head.php';
    include 'includes/navigation.php';
    $errors = array();


    $parent=0;
    $getURL='';
    if(isset($_GET['producttype']) && !empty($_GET['producttype'])){
        $getURL= htmlspecialchars((int)$_GET['producttype']); //gets prodcttype from URL and makes sure its an int
        $getURL=sanitize($getURL); 


        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM producttype WHERE ProductTypeID ='$getURL'";
        $results = $db->query($sql2);
        $parent2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
        $parent2=$parent2['ProductType'];
        if($parent2==null)//elimantes possibilty of user from inputting non existing ProductTypeIDs and if he/she does he will be redirected
        {
            header('Location: childProdTypes.php');
        }else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM producttype WHERE ProductTypeID = '$getURL'";
            $url_query = $db->query($sql);
            $prod_type = mysqli_fetch_array($url_query);
            $buffer=$prod_type['ProductType'];
            $buffer2=$buffer;
            $subtable2= $buffer.'type';
            $subtable3=$subtable2;
            $buffer=$buffer.'Type';
            $subtable=strtolower($subtable3);
            echo $subtable.'ras';
            echo 'Dollar Buffer:'.$buffer.'</br>';
            echo $buffer2;
            echo $subtable2;
            echo $subtable3;
            $specProdID=$buffer.'ID';
            echo 'Dollar $specProdID=='.$specProdID.'<br>';// Example == BookTypeID
            echo 'Dollar buffer:'.$buffer.'</br>';//Example == BookType
            echo 'Dollar subtable:'.$subtable.'</br>';//Example == booktype
            $editProdType=null;//to declare above and than delete

            $sqlsub="SELECT * FROM  $subtable ORDER BY $buffer";
            $sub_query = $db->query($sqlsub);
            //var_dump($subtable).'______________';


            //edit product sub-category     
if(isset($_GET['edit']) && !empty($_GET['edit'])){
    $edit_id = (int)$_GET['edit'];
    $edit_id = sanitize($edit_id);
    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM $subtable WHERE $specProdID = '$edit_id'";
    $edit_result=$db->query($sql3);
    $editProdType = mysqli_fetch_array($edit_result);

}

//delete product sub-category           
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
    $delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $subtable WHERE $specProdID = '$delete_id'";
    $db->query($sql);
    header('Location: childProdTypes.php?producttype='.$prod_type['ProductTypeID']); //refresh page to clear delete from URL in address bar
}




//add product sub-category      
if(isset($_POST['add_submit']) && !empty($_POST['add_submit'])){
        $prodType = sanitize($_POST['ProductType']);
        echo '+++';
        echo $subtable;
        echo '+++';
        echo $buffer;
        echo '+++';
        echo $prodType;
        echo '+++';
        echo $specProdID;
        echo '+++';

        //check if brand is blank
        if($_POST['ProductType']==''){
            $errors[] .='Cannot add an <b>empty input</b>!!!';
        }
        //check if ProductType exists in DB
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $subtable WHERE $buffer = '$prodType'";
        if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
            $sql="SELECT * $subtable WHERE $buffer = '$prodType' AND $specProdID != '$edit_id'" ;
        }
        var_dump($edit_id);
        $result=$db->query($sql);

        //how many rows in DB == true
        **$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count > 0){
            $errors[].= '<b>'.$prodType.'</b> already exists. Please enter e new Product Type!!!';
            var_dump($edit_id);**
        }
        //output errors
        if(!empty($errors)){
            echo display_errors($errors);
        }else{
            //Add ProductType to DB 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $subtable ($buffer) VALUES ('$prodType')";
            if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
                $sql = "UPDATE $subtable SET $buffer = '$prodType' WHERE  $specProdID = '$edit_id'";
            }
            $db->query($sql);
            header('Location: childProdTypes.php?producttype='.$prod_type['ProductTypeID']); //refresh page
        }
    }


$listdbtables = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($db->query('SHOW TABLES')),0); //array containing all DB table names
//var_dump($listdbtables);

//if statement to check if $subtable/current selected ProductType has its own sub category table)
if (in_array($subtable, $listdbtables)) {
    echo "FOUND!!";
}   else {
    //If table not found, user will be directed to another page and prompted if a new table needs to be created
    //echo'Product Type: '.$buffer.' does not have its own sub-category table yet. Kindly contact Head-Administrator to create table name: '.$subtable.'!!!';
    //sleep(3);
    header('Location: table.php?check=1&producttypetable='.$buffer.'&productSubCat='.$buffer2.'&tableName='.$subtable.'');

}


    ?>





    <h2 class='text-center'>Product Sub-Categories: <?= $prod_type['ProductType'] ;?>s</h2><hr>

    <div class="text-center">
    <form class="form-inline" action="childProdTypes.php?producttype=<?= $prod_type['ProductTypeID'] ;?><?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'?edit='.$edit_id:'');?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php 
                $prodTypeValue='';
                if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
                    $prodTypeValue = $editProdType[$buffer];

                }else{
                    if(isset($_POST['ProductType'])){
                        $prodTypeValue = sanitize($_POST[$buffer]);
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <label for="ProductType"><?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit':'Add'); ?> a Sub-Product Type:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ProductType" id="ProductType" class="form-control" value="<?= $prodTypeValue;?>">
            <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])):  ?>
            <a href="childProdTypes.php?producttype=<?= $prod_type['ProductTypeID'] ;?>&edit=<?= $sub_type[$specProdID] ;?>" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <input type="submit" name="add_submit" value="<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit':'Add') ;?> Product Type" class="btn btn-dark">
        </div>
    </form>
    </div><hr>



        <div class="row">
            <div class"col-md-6"></div>
            <div class"col-md-6">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-auto table-condensed" >
                    <thead id="tableDarkTheme">
                        <th>Product Type</th>
                        <th>Sub-Category</th>
                        <th>Options</th>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>


                <tr>
                    <?php while($sub_type = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_query)): ?>
                    <td>
                        <?= $prod_type['ProductType'] ;?>s
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?= $sub_type[$buffer]   ; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="childProdTypes.php?producttype=<?= $prod_type['ProductTypeID'] ;?>&edit=<?= $sub_type[$specProdID] ;?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                        <a href="childProdTypes.php?producttype=<?= $prod_type['ProductTypeID'] ;?>&delete=<?= $sub_type[$specProdID] ;?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <?php endwhile; }?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    else {
        //displayed when ?productid is non existant Example of cause user entered manually in address bar
        $prod_get = "SELECT * FROM producttype";
        $prodType = $db->query($prod_get);



        //$sqlcd="SELECT * FROM cdtype";
        //$sqlbk="SELECT * FROM booktype";
        //$sqlbr="SELECT * FROM bluraytype";
        //$result = $db->query($sql);

        ?>
        <h2 class="text-center">Product Subtypes</h2>
        <div class="text-center">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-auto table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <th>Select Product Subtype</th><hr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodType)) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="childProdTypes.php?producttype=<?= $parent ['ProductTypeID'];?>" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $parent ['ProductType']; ?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 



<?php
    }
    ?>  



<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.** Also check for [mysqli_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), since mysql does not throw the same kind of errors that PHP does, and can fail silently.

Comment: That's *a lot* of code you want us to debug for you.  Can you be more specific about where the problem first appears?  You claim "the $edit_id variable is outputting null", what specifically do you mean by that?  Where in all of your uses of that variable does it first have a `null` value?

Comment: The problem though is that the edit part is not working. From my amateur knowledge I recognized that maybe it is from the $edit_id varibale which is returning null, but I am not certain. Any help?

Comment: David it is in this part of the code: //how many rows in DB == true
        **$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count > 0){
            $errors[].= '<b>'.$prodType.'</b> already exists. Please enter e new Product Type!!!';
            var_dump($edit_id);**

Comment: @mariusmifsud: So `@edit_id` is `null` in that specific part of the code?  What's the problem then?  The only line of code there which *uses* `$edit_id` is just dumping it to the page.  If you take out that one statement, does the rest work?  If `$edit_id` isn't supposed to be `null`, where is it supposed to get its value?  Is that happening?  Is it losing its value along the way, or is that value never being set in the first place?  There's a lot of debugging you can do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is about your action in your form which is mistype

```
childProdTypes.php?producttype=<?= $prod_type['ProductTypeID'] ;?><?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'?edit='.$edit_id:'');?>"
```

here the url will look like this

```
domain.com/childProdTypes.php?producttype=22?edit=1
```

while he should look like this

```
domain.com/childProdTypes.php?producttype=22&edit=1
```

so you can't access to the $_GET['edit']

you should change the `?` by a `&` in the action in your form

Comment: That was it MacBooc. I was inspecting that for 3 hours, did not see it =]. Guess I need a break. I am coding for nearly 12 hours now. Thanks

Comment: please check out also about sql injesction and how to ask a question on this site :) was hard to catch the problem

Comment: I need to look into the formatting of posts, its a bit confusing to be honest. Will do for the sql injection as it would be nice to include some security features in it. Any other suggestions apart sql injection in regards of security?

Comment: i don't know how works your site entirely, but should look also about XSS because of you input type="text", but clearly the first thing is prepared statement for your sql query